# Manifest Placholder changing value of BuildConfig property

Tags: android, manifest

I've followed a tutorial on how to secure your API keys and it led me to placing my API keys inside the `gradle.properties` file. This allowed me to access the keys using `BuildConfig.apiKey`.  I've set it up as follows:

**gradle.properties**

```
apiKey=mykeyishere
```

**build.gradle (app)**

```
def API_KEY = '"' + apiKey + '"' ?: '"API Key: Not provided"'
defaultConfig {
    ...

    each { type ->
        type.buildConfigField STRING, 'apiKey', API_KEY
    }

    manifestPlaceholders = [
        MY_KEY: API_KEY
    ]
}
```

**manifest**

```
<meta-data
    android:name="apiKey"
    android:value="{$MY_KEY}" />
```

So far, everything works except for the manifestPlaceholders. When I hardcode the string or use `strings.xml` I don't get any problems when it comes to accessing the service I'm using (I'm using Facebook and Google for sign in) but when I use the manifestPlaceholders it errors out.